# Extract utc format for datetime object in a new Python column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

Be the following pandas DataFrame:

```
|      ID      |     date                              |
|--------------|---------------------------------------|
|     0        |        2022-03-02 18:00:20+01:00      |
|     0        |        2022-03-12 17:08:30+01:00      |
|     1        |        2022-04-23 12:11:50+01:00      |
|     1        |        2022-04-04 10:15:11+01:00      |
|     2        |        2022-04-07 08:24:19+02:00      |
|     3        |        2022-04-11 02:33:22+02:00      |
```

I want to separate the date column into two columns, one for the date in the format "yyyy-mm-dd" and one for the time in the format "hh:mm:ss+tmz".

That is, I want to get the following resulting DataFrame:

```
|      ID      |     date_only           | time_only      |
|--------------|-------------------------|----------------|
|     0        |        2022-03-02       | 18:00:20+01:00 |
|     0        |        2022-03-12       | 17:08:30+01:00 |
|     1        |        2022-04-23       | 12:11:50+01:00 |
|     1        |        2022-04-04       | 10:15:11+01:00 |
|     2        |        2022-04-07       | 08:24:19+02:00 |
|     3        |        2022-04-11       | 02:33:22+02:00 |
```

Right now I am using the following code, but it does not return the time with utc +hh:mm.

```
df['date_only'] = df['date'].apply(lambda a: a.date())
df['time_only'] = df['date'].apply(lambda a: a.time())
```

```
|      ID      |     date_only           |time_only |
|--------------|-------------------------|----------|
|     0        |        2022-03-02       | 18:00:20 |
|     0        |        2022-03-12       | 17:08:30 |
|    ...       |        ...              |  ...     |
|     3        |        2022-04-11       | 02:33:22 |
```

I hope you can help me, thank you in advance.

Comment: Because time zone rules (and respective UTC offsets) depend on dates, UTC offsets of certain times only make sense in combination with a date. So why do you want to separate the two?

Comment: @FObersteiner I simply want to separate it by table format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert column to datetimes and then extract [`Series.dt.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.date.html) and times with timezones by [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df['date_only'] = df['date'].dt.date
df['time_only'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S%z')
```

Or split converted values to strings by space and select second lists:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df['date_only'] = df['date'].dt.date
df['time_only'] = df['date'].astype(str).str.split().str[1]
```

Comment: Note that `.dt` will only work if `df["date"]` already is a datetime. If it is not you should parse it as such first using [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)

Comment: Using your code I get the following error: ```ValueError: Tz-aware datetime.datetime cannot be converted to datetime64 unless utc=True```